# Effect of setting -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem JVM flag to false

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I was referred to this GC pause [issue](http://www.evanjones.ca/jvm-mmap-pause.html); it suggests setting `-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem` JVM flag to `false`. My question is what happens when we set this flag to `false`,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Then `/tmp/hsperfdata*` won't be written. Which, according to [hotspot-runtime-dev](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-runtime-dev/2015-March/014324.html) discussions,  will prevent some performance monitoring command line tools from discovering running VMs automagically. They can still attach to the running process if the PID is specified explicitly.

Comment: Yup, it will stop the monitoring tools like JConsole and VisualVM. Thanks.

Comment: from the doc "They can still attach to the running process if the PID is specified explicitly." how do it locally without JMS ?